# Why "bad file descriptor" appears only in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client

why does the sendto function return error: Bad File descriptor? **This only happens on Linux** (in Windows it works properly).
Here is my code:
json object hb is a classical json object, such as     `{ "name": "alfa", "surname": "beta"}`, converted to string by its method

```
int fd;
    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
    print_time();
    perror("Socket failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
//memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(9900);
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.96");
char ui_request_str[] = "";

strcpy(ui_request_str, json_object_to_json_string(hb));

  if (sendto(fd, ui_request_str, strlen(ui_request_str), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        debug_level > 0 && printf("message sent: %s\n", ui_request_str);
    }

    close(fd);
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: `char ui_request_str[] = "";` makes `ui_request_str` just one byte, so the following `strcpy` corrupts memory.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks, but sadly the problem was not it.

Comment: If you show _how_ you fixed it, and do what comment `1` suggests, it will be possible to people to identify the problem you are asking for help on.

Comment: There is no need to use `strcpy()` in this situation at all: `const char *ui_request_str = json_object_to_json_string(hb); sendto(..., ui_request_str, strlen(ui_request_str), ...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### problem

Your problem comes from memory that you don't allocate:

```c
char ui_request_str[] = "";
strcpy(ui_request_str, json_object_to_json_string(hb));
```

Of first line, you allocate a one bytes array.
On second line, you try to write the memory you reserved with the output of `json_object_to_json_string`

You are code generates a buffer overruns:

From man [strcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy):

> **Bugs**
> If the destination string of a `strcpy()` is not large enough, then anything might happen. Overflowing fixed-length string buffers is a favorite cracker technique for taking complete control of the machine. Any time a program reads or copies data into a buffer, the program first needs to check that there's enough space. This may be unnecessary if you can show that overflow is impossible, but be careful: programs can get changed over time, in ways that may make the impossible possible.

### solution

Don't make `ui_request_str` an array, make it a pointer:

```c
char * ui_request_str[];
ui_request_str = json_object_to_json_string(hb);

if (NULL == ui_request_str) {
    perror(";json_object_to_json_string");
    exit(0);
}

if (sendto(fd, ui_request_str, strlen(ui_request_str), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
{
    perror("Error");
}
else
{
    debug_level > 0 && printf("message sent: %s\n", ui_request_str);
}
```